# How do I install a driver for an Nvidia Geforce 310m?

Tags: 11.04, nvidia

I installed Ubuntu 11.04. I can not install my nvidia Geforce 310m driver.

I active it by Hardware Drivers (recomended) but it is not in use. I ran this command in terminal `sudo nvidia-xconfig` then restarted my computer.

My computer after restarting can not load login window and it is black. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a Sony Vaio VPCCW laptop, you may follow the below instructions. Note that the configuration details for the Nvidia GT 310M cards may be different across machines. For example, some manufacturers may implement some kind of hybrid graphics (like Optimus). For more details on that, see [Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969)

From [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9058304&postcount=9) on the Ubuntu Forums

1. Download >[sonycw.txt](http://ubuntuforums.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=141988&d=1262341882)< to your `/home/username/` directory.

**Note bodhi.zazen:** You probably need to have an account on the forums to download that file, I could not find another option, sorry.

**Note bodhi.zazen:** - I left the sonycw.bin link as it may help some. If you do not have a sony, try the nvidia driver without the sonycw.bin. If it does not work, google search for your hardware and a more appropriate EDID.

2. Rename `sonycw.txt` to `sonycw.bin`
3. Open terminal and paste these commands.

   ```
   sudo mv /home/your_user_name_here/sonycw.bin /etc/X11/
   gksu gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
   ```
4. Paste this in xorg.conf and then save:

   ```
   Section "Device"
   Identifier "Device0"
   Driver "nvidia"
   VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"
   Option "ConnectedMonitor" "DFP-0"
   Option "CustomEDID" "DFP-0:/etc/X11/sonycw.bin"
   EndSection
   ```
5. Install nvidia-glx-185

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-glx-185
   ```
6. Restart the computer and your done

for additional information see

http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=140482&page=2

Comment: This information only applies to the mentioned laptop model, using it with other machine may damage it (due to forcing EDID). I've seen GT310M cards which are Optimus-alike for which http://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969 may help